# Uniqueness of $N$ with given remainders modulo primes, using the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

We know that if we have information on $$N\bmod p_i$$ where $p_i$ are primes at every $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ where $m\in\Bbb N$ is such that $\prod_{i=1}^mp_i<N$, then we cannot reconstruct $N$ by CRT. We need to have $\prod_{i=1}^mp_i>N$.

My simple query is if $m$ is such that $\prod_{i=1}^mp_i\gg N$ then do we have any ambiguity in reconstruction? Or do any $m$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^mp_i>N$ suffices?

In general how do we reconstruct $N$ assuming number of bits in $N$ is known?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Well, $N + \prod_{i=1}^m p_i$ will always satisfy the same modular relations as $N$, will it not?

Comment: so we cannot reconstruct $N$ from residues?

Comment: Not uniquely (for a finite amount of residues, at any rate).

Comment: Page 74 https://books.google.com/books?id=-8wuH5AwbwMC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=reconstructing+integers+from+residues&source=bl&ots=tX92buMeS4&sig=uF8oybqjsytYSaQ8TvaLL07s-7A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEYQ6AEwCGoVChMI4d7Yp77QyAIVCsFjCh2vAgSd#v=onepage&q=reconstructing%20integers%20from%20residues&f=false

Comment: I suspect the point there is that unsigned four-byte integers are bounded in magnitude by $2^{32}-1$, and thus if $\prod_{i=1}^m p_i > 2^{32}-1$ then you can essentially reconstruct $N$ uniquely, because we have the additional information that $0 \leq N \leq 2^{32}-1$.

Comment: @GuyPaterson-Jones Look at page 74 in link I posted and http://www.uow.edu.au/~thomaspl/pdf/BajPla04.pdf.